# Looking for a search string in a file and printing next word in the same line

Tags: linux, perl, unix

For example, consider a file "abc.txt" has following content:

```
#--------------- Module Id ---------------
MODULE_ID='ACXX'
MODULE_ID='BCXX'
MODULE_ID='CCXX'
```

Now, I want to search "MODULE_ID" keyword in that file and if found it should print value in that quotes i.e. `"1"`.
Can I know how to do that in Linux?

I tried with following but couldn't succeed:

```
grep -o 'MODULE_ID='[^']*'' uk.spec > results.txt

grep -Po 'MODULE_ID="\K.*?(?=")' uk.spec 

perl -ne 'if(m/MODULE_ID="(.*?)"/){ print $1 . "\n"; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die $!;

while (<$fh>)
{
    chomp;
    if (m/^MODULE_ID='(.*)'/)
    {
        print qq{"$1"}, "\n";
    }
}

____DATA____
MODULE_ID='ACXX'
MODULE_ID='BCXX'
MODULE_ID='CCXX'
```

Output:

```
"ACXX"
"BCXX"
"CCXX"
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple Perl solution:

```
#/usr/bin/perl -ne
chomp $_; if($_ =~ /MODULE_ID=(.*)/) { print "$1\n"; }
```

This can be run as a shell one-liner thusly:

```
perl -ne 'chomp $_; if($_ =~ /MODULE_ID=(.*)/) { print "$1\n"; }' abc.txt
```